# MVC 3 Framework Edit and Details problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

## Background and Problem

I have successfully produced a database, models from the database, and controllers which produced default pages. The current problem that I am having is Edit and Delete pages, they are constantly producing problems and have tried

1. Remove contexts and readd
2. Delete the models and everything and re-add

### The Problem statement that is produced when I click on the edit/delete pages from the details page:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'Olympics2012.Controllers.AthleteController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'Olympics2012.Controllers.AthleteController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

### Controller Edit Code

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        
        Athlete athlete = db.Athletes.Find(id);
        return View(athlete);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Athlete athlete)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(athlete).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(athlete);
    }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the Edit action with the id as a parameter.  What is the value of id?

Comment: The value of the id is a primary key from the Athletes table in the database

Comment: Okay - why is the parameter nullable if it corresponds to a primary key?

Comment: Not sure, that's the constant error that keeps being produced every time I run and test the application

Answer (score 1):

Hi, try to pass an int value to the Find method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id.HasValue) 
    {
        Athlete athlete = db.Athletes.Find(id.Value);
        return View(athlete);
    }

    // A null-value has been passed
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And second: do your edit links contain id of the item to be edited?

For example: http://[site_name]/[controller_name]/Edit/[id]

If you did not specify an id, then you should do something like this (in the 'SomeView.schtml' file, in case you use Razor engine):

```
//...
@foreach(var item in [elements_container].Elements)
{
    //...
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
    //...
}
//...
```

Comment: I think I found what the problem was, some of my methods were labelled wrongly, some had ViewResult but once changed to ActionResult seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Edit method to:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

Comment: Have you checked that id contains a value?

What do your routes look like?

Comment: Think i found problem it isn't getting the ID from the details page because when clicking on the edit page link the route looks: http://localhost:63237/Athletes/Edit but when I added a value it worked

Comment: Okay - glad you got it sorted.  I find using FIDDLER2 is useful for problems like routing.  Maybe it will help you too.